# Symfony Doctrine Mapping:Import & Table Association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, command-line-interface

I am working with Symfony 2.3 on a new project using an existing database with numerous associations - many-to-many, one-to-many etc. During my initial import last week, I found somewhere in the docs stipulated that a doctrine:mapping:import would generate orm.yml files of my database which it did without a hitch. However, I also see that only ManytoOne relationships are generated in the yml files ... not any other kind of associations.

My statement was:

```
 $ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import –em=buv DBImportTestBundle yml
```

Also, I did a generate entities to create classes and basic CRUD for each table using:

```
 $ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities DBImportTestBundle
```

This also worked EXCEPT that I do not see any annotated associations generated in the doc blocks for any of the entity properties.

I'm looking through the docs but do not see any specific information on the exact requirements for associations on imported dbs. It could be I'm not looking in the right place.

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to maintain my db schema within symfony/doctrine ... My understanding was that I would need to explicitly define certain associations manually but I'm not sure what the exact requirements would be OR if perhaps I'm simply not passing in the correct arguments to create my annotated associations via generate:entities.

Can someone point me to any docs that refer to what I'm talking about or explain the proper approach to defining complex associations within doctrine? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src`  to generate entity classes with annotation mappings, before running : 
`$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities DBImportTestBundle`

[there is a cookbook for that](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)